# Is it ok to post someone's question in general chat?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, chat

I stumbled accross a question which I thought was very well written and didn't get as much attention as it deserved, and/or the answers aren't complete enough, other than putting a bounty on it there isn't much to be done to make it more visible, is it ok for me to ask in the general chat-room for people to give it a look? Or is this not considered constructive? (If every good question was posted there, there'd be some serious chat-flooding) How could I best go around this so I'm aware of the policy of the site? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you are not in the middle of some other discussion and its a proper question feel free to post them on the the chat room. Don't over do it ofc, no flooding of information will you get any attention, but I see no reason why not.

Adding a bounty to the posts is probably the best option (premium spot for 7 days ftw) but also editing and fixing small issues with them will shoot the post straight to the top of the [active](https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=active) question list and give them a bit more visibility.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know editing posts put them back at the top, although doesn't this mean people could be tempted to make tiny, pointless edits to keep their post high? (As opposed to making one large edit to make the post better)

Comment: The system protect the site about tinny meaningless changes, I said small, but they still need to be valid ;)

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for clarifying everything!